# Safe lock/unlock without scope guard

Tags: c++, locking

I have to deal with a design restriction(dependency issues) to not use scope guard for a mutex.

Sample code:

```
template<typename MutexType>
class Test
{
    MutexType myMutex;

public:
    void f()
    {
        myMutex.Lock();
        //code with many returns here depending on conditions
        myMutex.Unlock();
    }
};
```

Is there other safe way of dealing with multiple returns without scope guards? How did this work before the concept was widely used? Is `goto` a good option instead of `return` considering exceptions are disabled?

Comment: Write your own scope guard if you cannot use someone else's. Problem solved. RAII was in C++ since inception and there is no other way that is both convenient and exception safe.

Comment: This is a complete lock guard: `template <class Mtx> class LockGuard{ Mtx & m_mtx; public: LockGuard(Mtx & mtx) : m_mtx(mtx){ m_mtx.lock(); } ~LockGuard(){ m_mtx.unlock(); } };`. If it can fit in a comment, it will likely fit in your code. There's no reason not to use a lock guard.

Comment: Yup. RAII has always been the right way to handle this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @VladLazarenko suggests in the comments, the best approach would be to simply write your own scope guard for this.

However, if for some obscure reason that's not possible, you can simply move all the `//code with many returns here depending on conditions` into a separate function and just call that function between the `Lock()` and `Unlock()` calls.

You mention you have exceptions disabled; if that was not the case, the above solution (nested function) would require an additional `try ... catch` construct in the outer function, then it would work as well.

Comment: One potential issue with this approach is that the other function may be called from many other places also and all of them have to use the same locks to synchronize the access to the function

Comment: @NipunTalukdar Certainly. But that's what comments are for. Also, the function's visibility should be minimised (it should definitely be `private` to say the least).